# When a lower tier quorum comes to its own consensus

Tags: consensus, history

Consider this simple scenario:

```
A <--- B

A.QUORUM_SET = [A]
A.THRESHOLD = 100

B.QUORUM_SET = [A,B]
B.THRESHOLD = 49
```

So `A` is a higher tier node that comes to consensus with itself. `B` is a lower tier node that comes to consensus with `1/2` nodes from the set `{A,B}`.

The two nodes get disconnected. `A` continues to reach consensus with itself while `B` gets disconnected but is still coming to consensus with itself. Someone submits a `createAccount` operation through `B`.

At some point the network comes backup. `A` and `B` are technically out of sync. `A` does not have `B's` new account. How can the two nodes sync up without changing any quorum configurations? Can this be done through archive histories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A and B cannot sync up with SCP.  This is an invalid configuration.  B is misconfigured, so should just dump its state and restart with better quorum slices.

SCP only guarantees agreement when there is quorum intersection.  (This is one of the reasons stellar-core makes it hard to assign <= 66% threshold.  In your example, B would have had to add the configuration line `UNSAFE_QUORUM=true` to its `stellar-core.cfg` file.)